# In Orchard CMS, is there a front end menu equivalent of the admin menu's "Local Nav"?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

By implementing `INavigationProvider`, I can add to the menu items in the admin menu. I can also call the `.LocalNav()` method to create local menu items (ie location sensitive tabs that appear across the top of an admin page such as the ones on the Themes or Modules pages).

I need to implement something similar for front end menus. I would like to add "Local Nav" items to specific pages, and then have them show up in a specific menu on page.

So far, I have found that I need to implement `INavigationFilter` to add menu items on the fly. However, I'm not sure if there is an equivalent of `.LocalNav()` in this instance.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: OK, just found out that `MenuItem` has a LocalNav property. I'm going to have a play about here and see if I can answer my own question

Comment: `MenuItem.LocalNav` does not appear to have any effect on front end menus, so I'm back to square one